# Why Golang grpc-gateway's GET route matches POST request?

Tags: rest, go

I found a "get" route will match both HTTP GET and HTTP POST requests.
For example:

```
rpc aaa(User) returns (User) {
  option (google.api.http) = {
  get: "/api/v1/aaa"
};
```

It matches both `curl -v -X GET -k https://127.0.0.1/api/v1/aaa` and `curl -v -X POST -k https://127.0.0.1/api/v1/aaa`.

I was wondering if it's possible to strictly match all routes including methods?

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

It is because you did not specify the content-type of the request.

## Long answer

By spec, it is allowed for you to encode your `GET` request into a `POST` method with `Content-Type: application/x-www-url-encoded`.

So the request routing table in grpc-gateway tries to fallback from `POST` method to `GET` when the Content-Type of your request is `application/x-www-url-encoded`.

ref.
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/grpc-io/Xqx80hG0D44/1gwmwBcnNScJ

> "(Note) URL has a length limitation (go/longer-urls). It's enfoced by some browsers and proxies. If your GET request exceeds the limitation, browser may reject to send them. You may change to use a POST request with content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded instead. If the POST + URL is already been mapped to another backend function, you shall add "X-HTTP-Method-Override: GET" header to override the HTTP method and obtain the correct mapping.

Comment: Thank you Yugui. It explains the behaviour of grpc-gateway, since it's from spec.

Comment: However, it's very confusing. A GET HTTP call always has the lenth limitation. The api designer needs to take care if the length of an api's URL may exceed the allowance. It should not be the responsibility of grpc-gateway to do the trick. If I define a "get" in .proto file, then ONLY "get" requests are able to reach it.

Comment: Is it possible to get `x-url-form-encoded` data over grpc? I haven't figured it out. Whenever I try and use `httpbody` from `googleapis` I get not found. Am I looking in the right place?